# Creating PDF with Rotativa and attaching to email

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email, pdf, rotativa

Am using Rotativa to generate a pdf gift voucher, which is then attached to an email and sent to the customer. If I use Rotativa to just generate the pdf as a file it works brilliantly but when I attach that file to an email it appears to lose quality. See pics below:

Good quality from generated pdf

[image]

Poor quality from emailed pdf

[image]

Code Below:

```
    public Byte[] pdfVoucher_file(string sk = "", int custInt = 0, string voucher_code = "")
    {
        var pdf = new ActionAsPdf("getVoucher/" + voucher_code, new { sk = sk, custInt = custInt })
        {
            FileName = "Voucher_" + voucher_code.ToString().Trim() + ".pdf",
        };

        Byte[] pdfData = pdf.BuildPdf(ControllerContext);
        return pdfData;
    }

    public void email_Voucher(string sk, string voucher_code)
    {
        try
        {
            int constId = 123;
            string toEmail = ""test@site.com"
            string mailBody = "Your Voucher";
            MemoryStream pdfStream = new MemoryStream(pdfVoucher_file(sk, constId, voucher_code));
            Attachment pdf = new Attachment(pdfStream, "Voucher_" + voucher_code.Trim() + ".pdf", "application/pdf");

            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage()
            {
                Subject = "Your Gift Voucher",
                Body = mailBody,
                From = new MailAddress("tickets@mysite.com")
            };
            mail.To.Add(toEmail);
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mail.Attachments.Add(pdf);

            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient
            {
                Port = 25,
                DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                Host = "my.mailserver.com"
            };
            client.Send(mail);
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
    }
```

Best guess is that it's something to do with converting it into a Byte[] object. Any ideas how I can improve the quality?

Comment: Ok. Slightly embarrassing. The issue was that good version was being viewed in Chrome and and bad via Adobe. If I open the bad one in Chrome it's fine. Think I'll just try and use a clearer font.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try to attach your PDF in the following manner:

1. Save the filestream as a file on your disk. Declare the saved file's full path as a variable called `attachmentFilename`
2. Use the following code, to attach the saved file to your email:

code:

```
Attachment attachment = new Attachment(attachmentFilename, 
MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf);
ContentDisposition disposition = attachment.ContentDisposition;
disposition.CreationDate = File.GetCreationTime(attachmentFilename);
disposition.ModificationDate = File.GetLastWriteTime(attachmentFilename);
disposition.ReadDate = File.GetLastAccessTime(attachmentFilename);
disposition.FileName = Path.GetFileName(attachmentFilename);
disposition.Size = new FileInfo(attachmentFilename).Length;
disposition.DispositionType = DispositionTypeNames.Attachment;

mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);
```

3. Delete the file again, for good meassure